# Should I change "nevertheless" in this sentence?

Tags: tense, conjunctions

For the sentence below could you tell me that I should change **nevertheless** to **however** or change **lent** to **had lent** or change something else?

My sister lent me some money; nevertheless, I couldn't have afforded the trip to France.

Comment: Is there any more context?

Comment: No. There is only this sentence.

Comment: I think *otherwise* is a better choice.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Ah, you too said it!

Comment: No, there is more context. You got this from a test question; that **is** context, and mighty important context at that. I will reopen this question when you put that vital information into the question, and not in a comment under somebody's answer.

Comment: @JR It's a test and and for me I've got only this sentence. I don't know a person who wrote this sentence cut this sentence from which context.

Comment: The fact that it is a test question **is** the context. If someone asks me, "Is this should I change X to Y in this sentence?" I might answer that question differently if the O.P. wrote the sentence, or a test service wrote the sentence, or Charles Dickens wrote the sentence. No one should need to ask which is the case; it should be stated in the question itself. Also, the fact that the test is asking you to **find an error in the sentence** is also context – that means we need to get in the mind of the test makers, and figure out what they wanted the test takers to determine was wrong.

Comment: As a supporting example, it's worth pointing out how [this user](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17594/quality-product-or-product-quality/17609#17609) answered one of your other questions after it was edited for the sake of clarity. The fact that the context was provided (i.e., "this came from a test question where we are supposed to find an error in the sentence") affected the answer greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Both are okay as they mean that your sister gave you some money for some time/temporary. You may also think of *otherwise* to put there in case you mean that **without that money** your trip could not have been possible. But out of those two...

> My sister lent me some money - sounds a recent activity to me over 
>   My sister had lent me some money *(could be quite long time back as compared to the previous one).*

Now *nevertheless* and *however* -

Both are okay and can be used. They are almost interchangeable but I fee that *however* still leaves some scope of debate for something you are discussing. *Nevertheless* is more tight and leaves no space for the same.

Comment: I think both are okay too but this is an error sentence from a test and I can't find an error.

Comment: You should talk about how _otherwise_ is a better word choice here. Words like _however_ and _nevertheless_ would be good if the trip couldn't have happened despite the extra money: _My sister lent me some money; nevertheless, I could not afford the trip to France._ If you want to express that you couldn't go were it not for her money, then _otherwise_ is indeed the correct word; _nevertheless_ and _however_ would be wrongly used in that context.